# What .NET functions should be better supported in Mono?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, mono

I'm trying to implement a Visual Studio Addin to support cross-platform development. The addon currently only warns developer when using unsupported functions but I also want to implement a feature that informs him about functions that are implemented but produce sideffects / are unstable etc.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate this!

Comment: VB.net is available under MONO isn't it?

Comment: yes! any .net code can be executed using mono (if all functions are implemented)

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Visual_Basic

Comment: Rich B, have you tried it? Because I tried several times and failed miserable, then eventually gave up. What was your experience like ?

Comment: @Slough: No I haven't, I have no reason to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono provides a utility to analyze application binary and check for mono support called Mono Migration Analyzer. You can probably read the source code to understand more about less supported features. You can even directly use run this tool with your add in and process the results.